# Google Url shortner giving error for url with Ip

Tags: java, android, url-shortener, google-url-shortener

I am using Google Url shorten API.
to shorten URL "http://demos.companyname.com:1339/"

but when I replace this URL "http://demos.companyname.com:1339/" with something like "http://36.186.69.8:1339/" it returns an error.

how to solve this problem?

My URL shorten code is:

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String address,String longUrl) {

```
    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // DefaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(address);

        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity("{\"longUrl\":\""+ longUrl+"\"}"));
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append("\n");

        }
        is.close();
        Log.e("getJSONFromUrl: ", sb.toString());
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // Parse the String to a JSON Object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    // Return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

error response:

```
   {"error":{"errors":
         [{"domain":"global","reason":"invalid","message":"InvalidValue","locationType":"parameter","location":"resource.longUrl"}],"code":00,"message":"Invalid Value"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of my knowledge, google URL shortener does not work for IP,
It only worked for mapped URL.

check below link to know if google can shorten your URL or not.

https://goo.gl/